# Java Ecommerce Recommendation giving empty scores

Tags: predictionio

We followed the following document to get a basic ecommerce recommendation engine up:

Template Used: pio template get PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-ecommercerecommendation 
Document followed: https://docs.prediction.io/templates/ecommercerecommendation/quickstart/

However we tweaked in a few steps to get the engine up and running:

1. engineFactory value was changed (this was not mentioned in the quickstart)
2. Imported data as per the quickstart document
3. Downloaded the postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar driver
4. Ran the following commands:
   pio build
   pio train -- --driver-class-path postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar
   pio deploy -- --driver-class-path postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar

Everything worked fine and then we tried to get recommendations. But we always got empty itemScores array. Could you please help us with this?

Here is my Engine.json

```
{
  "id": "default",
  "description": "Default settings",
  "engineFactory": "org.template.recommendation.RecommendationEngine",
  "datasource": {
    "params" : {
      "appName": "MyApp123"
    }
  },
  "algorithms": [
    {
      "name": "algo",
      "params": {
        "seed": 1,
        "rank": 10,
        "iteration": 10,
        "lambda": 0.01,
        "appName": "MyApp123",
        "similarItemEvents": ["view"],
        "seenItemEvents": ["buy", "view"],
        "unseenOnly": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This happens when system falls back on popular items, if there is not enough data for recommendation. We tested with adding more and more data we started getting positive responses for our items

Answer (score 0):

This happens when system falls back on popular items, if there is not enough data for recommendation. We tested with adding more and more data we started getting positive responses for our items

Ref : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/yyLc_Vjo6mk